# Create additional cpanel admins on shared hosting sites

Tags: linux, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I run in to this block many times to figure out a way to share cpanel access with another user without having to give them my cpanel admin username/password. Is there a way to create an additional cpanel users. In this case its godaddy.com but I am wondering in general as well.

That way I do not have to share my own access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no other way (at least at this moment). This is a cpanel feature that would be available in WHM version 64.x

You can read more details here:
https://features.cpanel.net/topic/multiple-cpanel-logins-cpanel-subusers

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

For every account in cpanel environment it creates just a single user to access the cpanel administration portal , you can allocate multiple user for it.

However with FTP you can grant the access to the data if needed by creating multiple FTP user account.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using `shared hosting` and in shared hosting you can not create another cpanel username/password.

But, my friend you can do one thing to (that is allow some limited access) you can create ftp account as number of ftp account allowed by hosting provider.

Your user can add/update/delete file for particular assigned directory.

Thanks 
Hope! this will help you